# Add a method other than setter/getter to cloud endpoints

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I write some codes as below on server-side and generate cloud endpoint class. The I generate cloud endpoints client library to use it in client-side.

```
package com.my;

import javax.jdo.annotations.IdentityType;
import javax.jdo.annotations.PersistenceCapable;
import javax.jdo.annotations.Persistent;
import javax.jdo.annotations.PrimaryKey;
import javax.persistence.Entity;

import com.google.api.server.spi.config.Api;
import com.google.api.server.spi.config.ApiMethod;
import com.google.api.server.spi.config.Named;

@PersistenceCapable(identityType=IdentityType.APPLICATION)
public class Process {

    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent
    private long UID;

    @Persistent
    private String Key;

/*  public Process(long uid, String ki){
        this.setUID(uid);
        this.setKey(ki);*/
    //}
    public long getUID() {
        return UID;
    }
    public void setUID(long uID) {
        UID = uID;
    }
    public String getKey() {
        return Key;
    }
    public void setKey(String key) {
        Key = key;
    }

    public void test(){
    }
}
```

Then on the client-side, when I try to use setters/getters it's working. But, I can't use test method. I checked generated library on client side and it doesn't have test method.

I have to use Datastore, so I need to have @Persistent. I also tried it with @ApiMethod, but it didn't work.

I would like to know how we can add methods other than setters/getters in cloud endpoints client library?
Thanks

Comment: This doesn't look like cloud endpoints (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/annotations). I think your confusing persistence api (jdo) with cloud endpoints. Of course you can use both but you should use separate classes for database entities and api methods.

Comment: Thanks for answering. After digging deeper, I think I'm confusing these two, as you said.

I can create class A with my methods and add @ApiMethod, so that the client can access them.

Then, I create another class B for datastore to access the database.

Now, I want to know if it's possible to integrate both, like using class A inside class B.

Comment: Google Endpoints is great framework, why only babies are interesting?!

Comment: Because babies are very smart.